# How to go to the next line in a matrix form and how to reduce the vertical space in a matrix

Tags: matrices

In fact after compiling the code below, the third matrx is outside the paper form, I want to have this matrix in the next line in the middle, also I want to reduce the vertical space in a matrix, I know in this example it's reduced but generally how can we reduce it.

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{30}{16}{12}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
[L_{ss}]= 
\begin{bmatrix}
 R_s & M_s & M_s \\ M_s & R_s & M_s \\ M_s & M_s & R_s
\end{bmatrix},
[L_{rr}]= 
\begin{bmatrix}
R_r & M_r & M_r \\ M_r & R_r & M_r \\ M_r & M_r & R_r
\end{bmatrix}
[M_{sr}]=[M_{rs}]^t= M_{sr}
\begin{bmatrix}
cos(\theta) & cos(\theta-4\pi/3) & cos(\theta-2\pi/3) \\ cos(\theta-2\pi/3) 
& cos(\theta) & cos(\theta-4\pi/3 \\ cos(\theta-4\pi/3) & cos(\theta-2\pi/3) 
& cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

For vertical spacing:
[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of `\DeclareMathSizes{12}{30}{16}{12}`?

Comment: Changing the font of an equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to use the `gathered` environment, and the `xmatrix*`  envoronments from `mathtools` (the columns alignment is an option`and  the medium-sized fractions from`nccmath`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{30}{16}{12}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array, nccmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
[L_{ss}]= \begin{bmatrix}
 R_s & M_s & M_s \\ M_s & R_s & M_s \\ M_s & M_s & R_s
\end{bmatrix},\qquad
[L_{rr}]=
\begin{bmatrix}
R_r & M_r & M_r \\ M_r & R_r & M_r \\ M_r & M_r & R_r
\end{bmatrix} \\[1.5ex]
[M_{sr}]=[M_{rs}]^t= M_{sr}
\begin{bmatrix*}[l]
\cos\theta & \cos\Bigl(\theta-\mfrac{4\pi}{3}\Bigr) & \cos\Bigl(\theta-\mfrac{2\pi}{3}\Bigr) \\[1.5ex]
\cos\Bigl(\theta-\mfrac{2\pi}{3}\Bigr) & \cos(\theta) & \cos\Bigl(\theta-\mfrac{4\pi}{3}\Bigr) \\[1.5ex]
\cos\Bigl(\theta-\mfrac{4\pi}{3}\Bigr) &\cos\Bigl(\theta-\mfrac{2\pi}{3}\Bigr) & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix*}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

To answer a question in the comments, this code for the last matrix:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & \cos\Bigl(\theta-\mfrac{4\pi }{3}\Bigr) & \cos\Bigl(\theta-\mfrac{2\pi }{3}\Bigr) \\[1.5ex]
\cos\Bigl(\theta-\mfrac{2\pi }{3}\Bigr) & \cos \theta  & \cos\Bigl(\theta-\mfrac{4\pi }{3}\Bigr) \\[1.5ex]
\cos\Bigl(\theta-\mfrac{4\pi }{3}\Bigr) &\cos\Bigl(\theta-\mfrac{2\pi }{3}\Bigr) & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
```

yields this result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Bernard but how about reducing the vertical space in a matrix see the new edited post and also I want to know how can I make cos(\theta) in the middle not aligned with the vertical expressions

Comment: @Twimo: to reduce the vertical spacing, use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{some number < 1}` before the matrix (put it with the matrix in a group if you want it to be local). However I had  to *increase* the spacing here – otherwise two consecutive rows touch each other. For your other question, I'll post a solution in a moment.

Comment: @twimo; Does the new code correspond to what you want?

Comment: Thank you so very much @Bernardeverything is fine but the cos \theta of the first and the third column are not in the middle even if I use {}\hfill

Comment: @Twimo: Oh! I hadn't understood you want them centred in all columns. In this case, simply remove the optional argument  `[l]`: all columns will be centred (it's the default). No `\hfill{}` to be used in this case.

Comment: Ah ok thank you so very much @Bernard  a true saver as always